# How to restrict the changes to URL from end user in angular

Tags: angular

I am using angular 7 in my application.
I would like to restrict the user to change URL manually.
How to do it let me know.
Please find below case also.

Case:I have redirecting user with below code. so the URL will not change but the component rendered into DOM.

```
this.router.navigate([(this.route.snapshot.data as any).redirectTo],
      {
        skipLocationChange: true, relativeTo: this.route
      });
```

so original route would be localhost:4200/dashboard/admin but due to above lines of code /admin will not show.
If user enter manually /admin or /user at the end of the URL then i want to remove /admin or /user.
How to do it

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box solution for your problem.

My suggestion would be to use a guard with the following flow:

1. When you navigate from your code, send something along the route (set a value in a service or something)
2. On your user/admin route add a Guard. In the guard if the value is not set, then return false, thus dissallowing the user to switch route. Reset the value for the next time.

For 1, I would avoid doing something like this:

this.router.navigate([(this.route.snapshot.data as any).redirectTo],
  {
    skipLocationChange: true, relativeTo: this.route, isManual: false
  });

The isManual will be able to be written in the url so it will be irrelevant. I would go with a shared data service or a state service. Plenty of material online on how to build either.

Hope this helps,
Thanos